# Try-Catch Powershell - Skip archiving log files if they already exist in the directory

Tags: powershell, try-catch

I'm still on my journey of learning powershell - my apologies in advance if I'm incorrectly presenting my question on this forum.

My co-worker helped me with a powershell script to help archive log files. It seems like we have it running as expected, but for some reason our **try/catch** statement isn't properly working. Specifically, we want the script to avoid moving files that already exist into our directories. I've compared this statement on other scripts where it is working, but I haven't been able to troubleshoot what the issue could be.

Any thoughts? This is what the script looks like so far:

```
#----- Script variables 

# variables with static data
$logpath = "C:\temp\log\"
$logname = "log-archive-test"
$lognameext = ".log"
# the variables below will be dynamically set later in the script
$Outputstr = ""
$DateVar = ""
$Datestr = ""
$TimeStr = ""
$logTimeStr = ""
$logfiletxt = ""

#-----  Get Date and Time
$FileDate = Get-Date -format yyyy-MM-dd
$Datestr = Get-Date -Format "MM/dd/yyyy"
$TimeStr = Get-Date -Format "HH:mm"


#----- Functions

# Write-File-Host - function to write to a log file and to console

function Write-File-Host 
( [String] $FileHostOutputText,
  [String] $FileHostOutputFile
)
{
  Process 
  {
    Write-Output $FileHostOutputText >> $FileHostOutputFile
  }
  End {Write-Host $FileHostOutputText}
}


#-----------------------------------------  create log destination and filename

$OutputdatafilenameTimeStr = $TimeStr -replace ":", ""
#$Outputdatafilename =  $sqlfile.SubString(0,$i) + " " + $FileDate + "T" + $OutputdatafilenameTimeStr + ".csv"
#$Outputdatatext = $AppOutDataDir + $Outputdatafilename
#$logTimeStr = $TimeStr -replace ":", ""
$logfiletxt = $logpath + $logname + "_" + $FileDate + "T" + $OutputdatafilenameTimeStr + $lognameext


function Format-YearMonth ([datetime]$date) {
    # simply output a string like "2021_01"
    return '{0:yyyy_MM}' -f $date
}

$sourcePath = 'C:\Users\test\Desktop\log'
$targetPath = 'C:\Users\test\Desktop\log\Archive'
$thisMonth  = Format-YearMonth (Get-Date)

#--------------------------------------------- Announce starting of Log Archiving

$Datestr = Get-Date -Format "MM/dd/yyyy"
$TimeStr = Get-Date -Format "HH:mm"
$Outputstr = $Datestr + " " + $TimeStr + ": ==================== Starting the Archiving of Log Files"
Write-File-Host $Outputstr $logfiletxt    


Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath -File | 
    # filter out the files that have a LastWriteTime for this year and month

    Where-Object {(Format-YearMonth $_.LastWriteTime) -ne $thisMonth } |
    ForEach-Object {
        # Set destination Path
        $Directory = Join-Path -Path $targetPath -ChildPath (Format-YearMonth $_.LastWriteTime)
        # Create directory if it doesn't exsist

#--------------------------------------------- Announce creation of directory if it doesn't exist 
$Datestr = Get-Date -Format "MM/dd/yyyy"
$TimeStr = Get-Date -Format "HH:mm"
$Outputstr = $Datestr + " " + $TimeStr + ": ----------- Create directory $Directory if it doesn't exsist"
Write-File-Host $Outputstr $logfiletxt    

        if (!(Test-Path $Directory)) {
            $null = New-Item $Directory -type Directory
        }
        Write-Host "Moving file '$($_.FullName)' to '$Directory'"
        # Move File to new location

#--------------------------------------------- Announce moving of files to the Directory
$Datestr = Get-Date -Format "MM/dd/yyyy"
$TimeStr = Get-Date -Format "HH:mm"
$Outputstr = $Datestr + " " + $TimeStr + ": ----------- Moving file '$($_.FullName)' to '$Directory'"
Write-File-Host $Outputstr $logfiletxt    

   try {    $_ | Move-Item -Destination $Directory  }
  
  catch {   $Datestr = Get-Date -Format "MM/dd/yyyy"
            $TimeStr = Get-Date -Format "HH:mm"
            $Outputstr = $Datestr + " " + $TimeStr + ": ----------- File '$($_.FullName)' already exists in '$Directory'"
            Write-File-Host $Outputstr $logfiletxt    }
    }

#------------------------------------------------- Announce end of Log Archiving

$Datestr = Get-Date -Format "MM/dd/yyyy"
$TimeStr = Get-Date -Format "HH:mm"
$Outputstr = $Datestr + " " + $TimeStr + ": ==================== Archiving completed."
Write-File-Host $Outputstr $logfiletxt
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `-ErrorAction Stop` or `-EA Stop` to `Move-Item`. Otherwise, It is set to default `Continue` which means `Print error to output and generate NO exception`. So, if there is no exception, `try` block has nothing to catch and code doesn't hit `catch` block.

When `-ErrorAction` is set to `Stop`, it generates `ActionPreferenceStopException` whick triggers exception catch mechanism in `try` block.

Alternatively, you can use native .Net method [`[System.IO.File]::Move(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.file.move?view=net-5.0) that always generates exceptions.

[ErrorActionPreference](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables?view=powershell-7.1#erroractionpreference)

Comment: to add to this, adding `throw` in your `try` block will output non-terminating errors to your `catch`.

Comment: You could also just avoid the exception and try/catch block altogether and properly check for the existence of the file with `if (Test-Path $destinationpath) { error handling/logging} else { Move file }`.  What fun would that be though? :)